# Secure_ssl_redirect not working in django

Tags: python, django, http, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to redirect my django application which was running previously in http:// to https://

In settings.py file I added:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER =( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO','https')
```

Still it didn't redirect or show any error. I tried without secure_proxy_ssl_heade, it didn't work.